# Longest arithmetic subsequence

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, number-theory

Given a non empty finite sequence of integers, return an arithmetic subsequence of maximal length.

If there are multiple of the same maximal length, any of them can be returned.

#### Definitions:

An *arithmetic* sequence is a sequence \$a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4),...\$ such that there is a constant \$c\$ such that \$a(m+1)-a(m) = c\$ for all \$m\$. In other words: The difference between two subsequent terms is constant.

Given a sequence \$b(1),b(2),b(3),b(4),...\$ a *subsequence* is a sequence \$b(s(1)),b(s(2)),b(s(3)),b(s(4)),...\$ where \$1 <= s(1)\$ and \$s(m) < s(m+1)\$ for all \$m\$. In other words: Take the original sequence and remove as many entries as you want.

#### Examples

```
Input                     Output
[4,1,2,3,6,5]             [1,3,5] or [1,2,3]
[5,4,2,-1,-2,-4,-4]       [5,2,-1,-4]
[1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1]       [1,1,1,1,1] or [1,2,3,4,5]
[1]                       [1]
```

Some longer test cases:

```
Length: 25
Input: [-9,0,5,15,-1,4,17,-3,20,13,15,9,0,-6,11,17,17,9,26,11,5,11,3,16,25]
Output: [15,13,11,9] or [17,13,9,5]

Length: 50
Input: [35,7,37,6,6,33,17,33,38,30,38,12,37,49,44,5,19,19,35,30,40,19,11,5,39,11,20,28,12,33,25,8,40,6,15,12,27,5,21,6,6,40,15,31,49,22,35,38,22,33]
Output: [6,6,6,6,6] or [39,33,27,21,15]

Length: 100
Input: [6,69,5,8,53,10,82,82,73,15,66,52,98,65,81,46,44,83,9,14,18,40,84,81,7,40,53,42,66,63,30,44,2,99,17,11,38,20,49,34,96,93,6,74,27,43,55,95,42,99,31,71,67,54,70,67,18,13,100,18,4,57,89,67,20,37,47,99,16,86,65,38,20,43,49,13,59,23,39,59,26,30,62,27,83,99,74,35,59,11,91,88,82,27,60,3,43,32,17,18]
Output: [6,18,30,42,54] or [8,14,20,26,32] or [46,42,38,34,30] or [83,63,43,23,3] or [14,17,20,23,26] or [7,17,27,37,47] or [71,54,37,20,3]
```

#### Background

I got this idea when I recalled the Green-Tao-Theorem from 2004, which states that the sequence of primes contains finite arithmetic sequences of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒPIE$ÐfṪ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJQSUUkw5Bm4bmq&input=&args=WzQsMSwyLDMsNiw1XQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJQSUUkw5Bm4bmqCsOH4oKsRw&input=&args=WzQsMSwyLDMsNiw1XSwgWzUsNCwyLC0xLC0yLC00LC00XSwgWzEsMiwxLDMsMSw0LDEsNSwxXSwgWzFd).

#### How it works

```
ŒPIE$ÐfṪ  Main link. Argument: A (list of integers)

ŒP        Powerset; generate all sublists of A, sorted by length.
     Ðf   Filter the powerset by the link to the left:
    $       Combine the two atoms to the left into a monadic link.
  I           Compute all increments.
   E          Test whether they're all equal.
          This returns all arithmetic subsequences, sorted by length.
       Ṫ  Tail; extract the last sequence.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
ef!P{-VTtTy
```

[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ef%21P%7B-VTtTy&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B4%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C6%2C5%5D%0A%5B5%2C4%2C2%2C-1%2C-2%2C-4%2C-4%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C1%2C3%2C1%2C4%2C1%2C5%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%5D&debug=0)

```
          y  powerset of implicit input, generate all subsequences
ef       T   find the last subsequence (sorted increasing in length) where...
       Tt      bifurcate over tail, giving [1,2,3,4,5] [2,3,4,5]
     -V        vectorize over -, giving differences of each consecutive pair
    {          dedup (remove duplicate elements)
   P           pop, resulting in [] if all differences were equal
  !            boolean not, resulting in True if all differences were equal
```

Thanks to [@LeakyNun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) for a byte!

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 18 bytes

*1 byte saved (and 2  bytes added back) thanks to Luis!*

```
"GX@XN!"@dun2<?vx@
```

A fairly naive approach which brute force checks all ordered permutations of the input. Obviously this can take a while for longer sequences. To save a byte, I have started with the smallest sub-sequences (length = 1) and worked up to the larger sequences (length = N).

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkdYQFhOISJAZHVuMjw_dnhA&input=WzQsMSwyLDMsNiw1XQ)

**Explanation**

```
                % Impilicitly grab input array (N)
"               % For each value in this array
    G           % Explicitly grab the input
    X@          % Loop index, will be [1, 2, ... length(N)] as we iterate
    XN          % Determine all permutations of k elements (nchoosek). The output is 
                % each k-length permutation of the input as a different row. Order doesn't 
                % matter so the result is always ordered the same as the input
    !           % Take the transpose so each k-length permutation is a column
    "           % For each column
        d       % Compute the difference between successive elements
        un      % Determine the number of unique differences
        2<?     % If there are fewer than 2 unique values
            vx  % Vertically concatenate everything on the stack so far and delete it
            @   % Push the current permuatation to the stack
                % Implicit end of if statement
                % Implicit end of for loop
                % Implicit end of for loop
                % Implicitly display the stack
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! I always wondered how to get the loop iteration #.

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh good catch, you're right. That double `diff` gives an empty array which can't be negated.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
►oEẊ-Ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0XfmuD3d16T7cOe3////RpjomOkY6uoY6ukDSBIhiAQ)

### Explanation

The return value of `E` is useful here for getting the longest list that satisfies a condition.

```
►oEẊ-Ṗ   Implicit argument: a list.
     Ṗ   List of all its subsequences.
►        Find one that maximizes:
 o        Composition of two functions:
   Ẋ       1. Apply to adjacent elements:
    -         Subtraction.
  E        2. Are all elements equal?
              Returns length+1 if they are, 0 if not.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>124</s> <s>115</s> <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```python
p=[[]]
for n in input():p+=[x+[n][:2>len(x)or n-x[-1]==x[1]-x[0]]for x in p]
print max(p,key=len)
```

Very slow and memory intensive. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/BjAtUE).

#### Alternate version, 98 bytes

```python
p={()}
for n in input():p|={x+(n,)[:2>len(x)or n-x[-1]==x[1]-x[0]]for x in p}
print max(p,key=len)
```

This completes all test cases instantly. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/gQwG9c).

Comment: byte or speed, that is the question

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth [checkout 8593c76, March 24th](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/commit/8593c7647dad748d523ebdc3d7c625c30fe9a9f3), 10 bytes

```
efq-VTtT)y
```

This is exactly the same as Doorknob's answer, except that back in march, there was a 2 byte function (`q ... )`) which checked whether all of the elements of a list were the same, which is the same as `!P{`, which is the best you can do currently.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 157 bytes

```
a=>{for(m=i=0,l=a.length;i<l;i++)for(j=i;++j<l;)for(t=n=a[k=i],c=0;k<l;k++)a[k]==t&&(t+=a[j]-n,++c>m)?q=a[m=c,p=n,j]-n:q;return a.slice(-m).map(_=>(p+=q)-q)}
```

Almost 20 times longer than the Jelly answer... Ungolfed:

```
function subsequence(a) {
    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            var target = a[i];
            var count = 0;
            for (var k = i; k < a.length; k++) {
                if (a[k] == target) {
                    count++;
                    target += a[j] - a[i];
                    if (count > max) {
                        max = count;
                        start = a[i];
                        step = a[j] - a[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var result = new Array(max);
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        result[i] = start + step * i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
à ñÊkÈän än d
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4CDxymvI5G4g5G4gZA&input=WzQsMSwyLDMsNiw1XQotUQ)